# Javascript: POST to new window

Tags: php, javascript, post

I'm having trouble submitting some hidden form data via post from the following function:

```
function displayCertificate()
{
    window.open("../mailer.php","certificate","width=500,height=400,status=1")
} 
var sHTML = "";
sHTML += '<FORM id="quizResults" method="POST" action="/articulate/mailer.php" enctype="text/plain" target="certificate" onSubmit="displayCertificate()">';
sHTML += '<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="name" VALUE=\'' + g_arrResults[0].strStudentResponse + '\'>';
sHTML += '<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE=\'' + g_arrResults[1].strStudentResponse + '\'>';
sHTML += '<br><input type="submit"><br>';
sHTML += '</FORM>';
alert(g_arrResults[0].strStudentResponse);
document.getElementById("divEmail").innerHTML = sHTML;
document.getElementById("quizResults").submit();
```

What I need is for a new window to open up with the information I sent to it via POST. The window pops up fine, and firebug shows that the POST was successful but the data doesn't seem to be sent to my new window.

Here is my **mailer.php:**

```
<?php
print("name: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
print("email: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
?>
```

Very simple yet it is outputting: `name: email:`

Can anyone see why this would be happening? My solution has to be plain javascript (so no libraries please).

Thanks.

edit in response to alessioalex:

Output of `console.log(g_arrResults)` is an array like so:

```
[QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=1, strQuestion=" ", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=2, strQuestion=" ", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=3, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=4, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=5, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=6, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=7, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=8, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=9, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=10, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=11, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}, QuestionResult { nQuestionNum=12, strQuestion="A, B or C?", more...}]
```

Here is an example of the first object in the array:

```
bFound
    false

dtmFinished
    Date {Thu Nov 17 2011 12:54:29 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}

nPoints
    "0"

nQuestionNum
    1

strCorrectResponse
    "&nbsp;"

strInteractionId
    "I4e28818f-4014-418c-a6e4-863679014098"

strLatency
    "1862"

strObjectiveId
    "I4e28818f-4014-418c-a6e4-863679014098"

strQuestion
    " "

strResult
    "neutral"

strStudentResponse
    "Peter Rabbit"

strType
    "fillin"
```

Comment: What does a 

    var_dump($_POST); 

give you? Seems like it is something on the server side.

Comment: @WillemMulder That's telling me there is no POST data: `array(0) { } `

Comment: Can you do a console.log(g_arrResults); in JavaScript? I want to see what are you sending (if there is actual data).

Comment: forms can submit to target of "_blank".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the window.open code and try adding target="_blank" to your form:

```
<FORM target="_blank" id="quizResults" method="POST" ...>
```

Comment: Already tried this before the `window.open`, same result didn't work.

Comment: Have you also removed the other target attr (target="certificate") from the form?

Comment: And also remove the enctype attribute from your form - tested and works

Comment: @George Then you've done something to block it, what mlitn posted is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the form to the pop up window document then auto submit it:

```
function displayCertificate()
{
    var win = window.open("","certificate","width=500,height=400,status=1");
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<FORM id="quizResults" method="POST" action="/articulate/mailer.php" enctype="text/plain" target="certificate" onSubmit="displayCertificate()">');
    win.document.write('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="name" VALUE=\'' + g_arrResults[0].strStudentResponse + '\'>');
    win.document.write('<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE=\'' + g_arrResults[1].strStudentResponse + '\'>');
    win.document.write('<br><input type="submit"><br>');
    win.document.write('</FORM>');
    win.document.close();
    win.document.getElementById('quizResults').submit();
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/VGUhk/) (using Google for sake of example).

Answer (score 0):

because you are trying to access page mailer.php before submitting the page

remove onsubmit() method from form tag

then try it will work